# Concatenate two columns using Update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have question regarding to updating data in a sql table.

I have three columns CA, CB , CC ( concatenation of Ca&CB).

```
CA   CB    CC    
1    A     1A    
2    B     2B
```

After update Ca or CB , CC should change according to value using a trigger.

```
CA   CB    CC    
1    D     1D    
2    C     2C
```

Computed column will not work since this table will be used by GIS tool and computed column is not showing up in their tool.

Any script or solution will be highly helpful.

thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f680908c-ce96-4b09-9edb-c5c1dce608cf/concatenate-two-columns-using-update-trigger?forum=transactsql) posted on msdn.

Answer (score 0):

This assume CA is identity column for Table1

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/JUPTU68548)**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgIssue
ON  Table1
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE A
SET A.[CC] = CAST( I.[CA] AS VARCHAR(16)) + I.[CB]
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN INSERTED I
    ON A.[CA] = I.[CA]


END;
```

Comment: I didn't make CA as identity but i can add extra field as Identity.